# Eliminar Jquery EventListener react.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Estoy trabajando un proyecto usando react.js, tengo un componente llamado chatBox el cual estoy usando en diferentes componentes, como se muestra en el ejemplo.

El problema que se presenta es que cada vez que renderizo un componente el evento click se esta duplicando. Existe alguna forma de hacer un removeEventListener cuando el componente sea desmontado?

```
var ChatBox = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount(){
      $('.addPrivate').on('click', function(){

      })
    },
    componentWillunMount(){
      console.log('removeEventListener')
    },
    render(){
      return <div>Chat <a href="javascript:;" className="addPrivate">Click</a></div>
    }
})

var Home = React.createClass({
    render(){
      return <div>
             <chatBox />
      </div>
    }
})

var Profile = React.createClass({
    render(){
      return <div>
             <chatBox />
      </div>
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que si utilizás el mismo componente más de una vez, vas a tener más de un elemento con `class='addPrivate'`

```
<a href="javascript:;" className="addPrivate">Click</a>
```

Lo correcto sería utilizar el handler directamente en el elemento

```
var ChatBox = React.createClass({
    onClick(event) { ... },
    render(){
      return <div>Chat <a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.onClick}>Click</a></div>
    }
})
```

No tendrías que estar manipulando DOMObjects directamente si utilizás react.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal usando [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

```
function onClickHandler() { ... };

... 

componentDidMount(){
  $('.addPrivate').on('click', onClickHandler)
},
componentWillUnmount(){
  $('.addPrivate').off('click', onClickHandler)
}
```

Salu2

Comment: Funciona bien muchas gracias, una pregunta mas como puedo acceder al element o this en la function onClickHandler para sacar unos atributos de addPrivate

Comment: lo usual es hacer `$(this)`. Recuerda que jQuery al invocar la funcion, establece el valor the `this` al elemento que recibe el evento. Por cierto, si te sirvio la respuesta, no olvides aceptarla. Salu2